# Can't bind to 'stackConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to build a tinder cards app in ionic2 following this tutorial https://devdactic.com/ionic-2-tinder-cards but got an error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'stackConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
```

Any solution?

Comment: I have done almost everything that is suggested over the forums. Still facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for it? if you have any working repo please share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

add these two modules  HttpModule,SwingModule  to your pagename.module.ts because the tutorial's using ionic 2 I think. We'll have to individually add the swing module to the  new page created.

[image: Individual page's module.ts]

Comment: i've added the module in pagename.module.ts but didn't worked. facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the SwingModule import in the app.module.ts. See the sample app config at https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular2-swing-example/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts`enter code here`

```
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [
       AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
       BrowserModule,
       FormsModule,
       HttpModule,
       SwingModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cards: Array<any>;
  stackConfig: any;
  recentCard: string = '';
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private http: Http, public navParams: NavParams,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
        this.stackConfig = {
           throwOutConfidence: (offsetX, offsetY, element) => {
           return Math.min(Math.abs(offsetX) / (element.offsetWidth/2), 1);
           },
          transform: (element, x, y, r) => {
          this.onItemMove(element, x, y, r);
          },
          throwOutDistance: (d) => {
            return 800;
          }
        };

      }
      ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Either subscribe in controller or set in HTML
        this.swingStack.throwin.subscribe((event: DragEvent) => {
          event.target.style.background = '#ffffff';
        });

        this.cards = [{email: ''}];
        this.addNewCards(1);
      }
```

Comment: use stackConfig: any; instead of  stackConfig: StackConfig;